# Routing http/2 requests to https services with a reverse proxy in node.js

Tags: node.js, https, reverse-proxy, aws-api-gateway, http2

I've been struggling during the last couple of days trying to configure a reverse proxy that receives requests in http/2 from the Internet and access services in AWS API Gateway in https.
I have been trying to use redbird but I cannot make it work.
In the code you see here, I am trying to route localhost requests in http/2 to an AWS S3 bucket to display a png file. So when I enter the url in the browser with http://localhost/myfileaddress the system routes it to S3 and shows me the file. This is of course not happening.

```
var proxy = require('redbird')({
port: 3000,
ssl: {
    http2: true,
    port: 3030,
    key: "../certs/mycert.key",
    cert: "../certs/mycert.csr"
}
});

proxy.register("localhost", "https://s3.amazonaws.com", {ssl: true});
```

These are the errors I see in the console:

{"name":"redbird","hostname":"Eleanor.local","pid":2016,"level":50,"err":{"message":"140736110211904:error:140A1175:SSL routines:ssl_bytes_to_cipher_list:inappropriate fallback:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/ssl_lib.c:1575:\n","name":"Error","stack":"Error: 140736110211904:error:140A1175:SSL routines:ssl_bytes_to_cipher_list:inappropriate fallback:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/ssl_lib.c:1575:\n"},"msg":"HTTPS Client  Error","time":"2017-10-06T12:01:35.849Z","v":0}
{"name":"redbird","hostname":"Eleanor.local","pid":2016,"level":50,"err":{"message":"140736110211904:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_srvr.c:1427:\n","name":"Error","stack":"Error: 140736110211904:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_srvr.c:1427:\n"},"msg":"HTTPS Client  Error","time":"2017-10-06T12:01:53.062Z","v":0}
{"name":"redbird","hostname":"Eleanor.local","pid":2016,"level":50,"err":{"message":"140736110211904:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_srvr.c:1427:\n","name":"Error","stack":"Error: 140736110211904:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_srvr.c:1427:\n"},"msg":"HTTPS Client  Error","time":"2017-10-06T12:01:53.064Z","v":0}
{"name":"redbird","hostname":"Eleanor.local","pid":2016,"level":50,"err":{"message":"140736110211904:error:140A1175:SSL routines:ssl_bytes_to_cipher_list:inappropriate fallback:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/ssl_lib.c:1575:\n","name":"Error","stack":"Error: 140736110211904:error:140A1175:SSL routines:ssl_bytes_to_cipher_list:inappropriate fallback:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/ssl_lib.c:1575:\n"},"msg":"HTTPS Client  Error","time":"2017-10-06T12:01:53.066Z","v":0}

Am I doing something wrong?
Please feel free to suggest another revert proxy module for node if there are better ones.

Thanks,

GA

Comment: Have you tried visiting http://localhost:3000/myfileaddress? Also are you getting an error message any where? In the browser or in the console?

Comment: Yes, Tried localhost:3000. I added the errors I see in the console to the questions.